# Can we connect SharePoint online to ODBC data

Tags: sharepoint-online, external-list

Can we connect SharePoint online to ODBC data? to read the ODBC data and update a sharepoint custom list?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried SharePoint ODBC Driver before?

The SharePoint ODBC Driver is a powerful tool that allows you to connect with live data from SharePoint and SharePoint Online, directly from any applications that support ODBC connectivity. Access SharePoint data like you would a database - read, write, and update SharePoint Lists, Contacts, Calendar, Links, Tasks, etc. through a standard ODBC Driver interface.

Reference: [SharePoint ODBC Driver](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CDATASOFTWARE.SharePointODBCDriver)